# Play store fails to update apps under lock screen

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop

I have noticed on my Sony Xperia Z1s running lollipop 5.0.1 that apps fail to install if I lock the phone or it times out. Apps do install in the background, though, if the phone is being used or unlocked in general. Because of this, updates tend to pile up. In fact, just before I had written this post, I had 30 updates waiting, and they all failed when I locked the phone.